# array search with exception in Java

Tags: java, arrays, exception

Can you please help me with this. I need to find a value in array and if there is no such a value make an exception about it.
i did wth if else in a loop it is print 4 time NOT FOUND. Thank you very much.

```
public class Search {
    public static int arraySearch(int [] array, int value){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] == value){
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
             
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = { 23, 6, 9, 10};
        arraySearch(array, 6);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should *return* a value, not print it. And if you end the loop without having returned (i.e., simply after the loop) just throw the exception.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean when you say *"i did wth if else in a loop it is print 4 time NOT FOUND"*?

Comment: when i add else after if ( else print Not found). I want to print one time not 4 time

Comment: Ok. No need for that `else` then, just return when you find the element and throw the exception at the end of the method (if you reach the end of the method it means you haven't found the element you were looking for. As an aside, in case you're also looking for a better design, I would expect such a method to return `true` if it finds a match and `false` otherwise, not an integer if it succeed and an exception in case it doesn't.

Comment: By the way, I noticed this is the second question you ask but in both cases you didn't accept any answer. You should. That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: ohh, I just didnt know about it. Yes you are right this my second question. RN i will accept it. I post seldom here, when i cant find the answer on ethernet by myself. I'm very grateful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, throwing an exception when searching for a missing element in an array is not really the best solution, but in another comment you say this is a requirement, so here it goes.

There are a couple of things we need to do

1. A custom exception we're going to throw, because there's no exception in the standard library for "I have not found an element in an array", and for good reason;
2. The `arraySearch` method needs to declare it throws the exception
3. The `arraySearch` method should *return* a value, not print it
4. If no value is returned (i.e. if we reached the end of the loop and have not returned yet) `arraySearch` should throw our custom exception
5. `main` needs to catch the exception and act accordingly

Here's the code. Be sure to understand it, don't just copy and paste it.

```
public class Search {

    private static class ElementNotFoundException extends Throwable {}

    public static int arraySearch(int [] array, int value) throws ElementNotFoundException {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] == value){
                return value;
            }
        }

        throw new ElementNotFoundException();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = { 23, 6, 9, 10};
        try {
            System.out.println(arraySearch(array, 60));
        } catch (ElementNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I suspect you misunderstood your homework and you actually need to return the *index* of the element you found, not its value (which is not very useful). I'll leave that as an exercise for you to solve.

Comment: Thank you very very much bro, I'm really sorry you wasted your time. Thanks. I did class and create the custom exception, just didnt know where to write try and catch. Now i get due to you. Thanks

Comment: @EdgarA8 don't worry, I'm doing this because I want to, not because of someone forcing me :) By the way, I suggest you consider the part I added at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: yes i red it. Just my teacher asked to find a value and if there is no such a value throw custom exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach. The actual exception throwing can be built in.

```
public class Search {
    public static int arraySearch(int[] array, int value) {
        int result = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length && result < 0; i++) {
            if (array[i] == value) {
                // Found! We want to know the index. We know the value
                result = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 23, 6, 9, 10 };
        System.out.println(arraySearch(array, 6));

    }
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of emphasizing that this is *not* a proper solution.

Comment: can you show me how to write that exception, please? I know how to write standard exceptions, but sometimes, I cant figure out

Comment: *can you show me how to write that exception, please?* If you *are* going to throw an exception (which I wouldn't as the absence of a sought value is not really an exceptional state) then you should really define a custom *checked* exception subclass. Let's call it `ValueNotFoundException`. Then you would check for `result == null` and if so, throw the exception.

Comment: i did class, I'm doing a task which say i need exception, I just dont know where to write try and catch blocks

Comment: @EdgarA8 it's not thrown because the element is found. Try and substitute 6 with, let's say 50 in the call to `arraySearch`, it will throw a `NullPointerException`. But as g00se said **this is not a good solution to your problem**, it's just a curiosity.

Comment: @g00se I saw this coming and wanted to downvote the answer, then thought better of it. But I would suggest this is more confusing than it needs to be and I think it would be better if you deleted it.

Comment: Mmm OK @Federico klez Culloca. Actually using `Integer` as a sentinel value type *could* be part of a proper solution, but to show how, I'd have to do too much of @Edgar AB's classwork